# Merge Stack Overflow accounts

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have my main account for StackOverflow that I use with 'log with Facebook'.

Unfortunately, I created another account using 'log in with Google account'. I would like to merge these two accounts, or at least that whenever I clic 'log in with Facebook', or 'log in with Google', it log me into the same account.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the Stackoverflow help page.

> I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
>   edit the ‘about me’ section of each profile to say “merge keep” and
>   "merge delete" and then [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). You will need to provide links to
>   the two profiles you would like to merge - we'll merge the one you
>   annotated "merge delete" into the one you annotated "merge keep".
>
> If you can't remember how to log into one of your accounts, [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery)
>   and enter the email address you used to create it.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts